# Combine 2 XML Output Statements into one XML file

Tags: sql, xml, dynamic

I've been working on outputting from SQL to XML and have finally come up with 2 queries that work fabulously for what I need with one problem.  I did these independently as I am a novice with XML and now I need to combine them into one file for output.  What I have is pretty complicated using dynamic SQL so I'm just going to post the dynamic part and exclude all of the variable and un-pivoting stuff I'm doing at the beginning.  If I could just get result set 1 to be at the top and result set 2 just below it would suffice.  I would like a wrapper tag (not sure if that's the term) as the very first and very last lines in this file.  I'm not sure if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong just by looking at the dynamic code but I thought it would be worth a try.  As I said, both of these work great but produce 2 separate files.  Thanks in advance!

EXEC ('

```
SELECT 
(SELECT GETDATE() AS STARTDATE,
    GETDATE() AS ENDDATE
FOR XML PATH(''RECDATE''),ELEMENTS, TYPE),

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS SURVEY_COUNT
FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract FOR XML PATH(''''), ELEMENTS, TYPE),

(SELECT ''PEPM'' as SERVICE,
    DataCol as VARNAME,
    Question as QUESTION_TEXT,
    AnswerValue as ANSWER_TEXT
from PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterCodeSheetExtract FOR XML PATH(''QUESTION''), ROOT(''QUESTION_MAP''), ELEMENTS, TYPE)
FOR XML PATH(''HEADER'')

SELECT PATID,CLIENTID,SERVICE,PATVISITDT,DATE,

(
    SELECT  VarName,Value
    FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract_AnalysisPivot P
    INNER JOIN PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract E ON E.PatVisitID = P.PatVisitID
    FOR XML PATH(''Response''), TYPE, ROOT(''Analysis'')
),
(
    SELECT  VarName,Value
    FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract_DemoPivot P
    INNER JOIN PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract E ON E.PatVisitID = P.PatVisitID
    FOR XML PATH(''Response''), TYPE, ROOT(''Demographics'')
)
 FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract
 FOR XML PATH(''PatientLevelData''),TYPE, ROOT(''PatientLevelData'')
')
```

Comment: Result Set 2 starts at the "SELECT PATID,CLIENTID,SERVICE,PATVISITDT,DATE," line

Comment: I got it a little closer and into one file by removing the "FOR XML PATH(''HEADER'') after result set one and moving that to the bottom and saying "FOR XML PATH(''DATA_EXPORT'')".  But that also removed my "HEADER" tag which I need

Comment: SELECT 
 (SELECT GETDATE() AS STARTDATE,
  GETDATE() AS ENDDATE
 FOR XML PATH(''RECDATE''),ELEMENTS, TYPE),

 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS SURVEY_COUNT
 FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract FOR XML PATH(''''), ELEMENTS, TYPE),

 (SELECT ''PEPM'' as SERVICE,
  DataCol as VARNAME,
  Question as QUESTION_TEXT,
  AnswerValue as ANSWER_TEXT
 from PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterCodeSheetExtract FOR XML PATH(''QUESTION''), ROOT(''QUESTION_MAP''), ELEMENTS, TYPE),

Comment: (SELECT PATID,CLIENTID,SERVICE,PATVISITDT,DATE,
(SELECT VarName,Value
FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract_AnalysisPivot P
INNER JOIN PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract E ON E.PatVisitID = P.PatVisitID
FOR XML PATH(''Response''), TYPE, ROOT(''Analysis'')
),

Comment: (
SELECT VarName,Value
FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract_DemoPivot P
INNER JOIN PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract E ON E.PatVisitID = P.PatVisitID
FOR XML PATH(''Response''), TYPE, ROOT(''Demographics'')
)
FROM PM_TEMP.dbo.tmpKansasCancerCenterExtract
FOR XML PATH(''PatientLevelData''),TYPE, ROOT(''PatientLevelData''))
FOR XML PATH(''DATA_EXPORT'')
')

Comment: I had to add ResultSet2 as 2 pieces as it was too long to post as a comment

Comment: Got it!!!  I added this after resultset 1:    FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE, ROOT(''HEADER'')),

Comment: thanks to anyone who reviewed this!